Pair of Pendants - One flickers then fails, but not right away; second bulb, second switch
When we remodeled the bathroom 7 years ago, we installed a pair of pendants over the vanity operated on the same switch. Last spring, the lefthand pendant began to flicker, then go off, then go on, then stay off, then willy-nilly go back on - erratic. We changed the bulb (LED) thinking it was bad and dying. It was fine for about two weeks (maybe 4). Then it repeated the above behavior. So we changed out the switch. (Mind you, the righthand pendant never has shown any similar behavior.) Lefthand pendant has been absolutely fine since April/May. Today the lefthand one repeated the past erratic/failing behavior. The only thing we can think of is that for some unexplainable reason the power to the lefthand pendant is compromised. We will be going up to the attic this weekend to look. But the mystery isn't that after 7 years a connection fails, but why after replacing the bulb, then the switch, that pendant worked fine for five months - no issue. Changing the switch did not involve any work with the connection in the attic. We changed the switch - it worked normally for five months, and now the lefthand pendant is failing again. Appreciate any brainstorming suggestions. One we're hating is to swap the fixtures and see if the pendant that has been working fine repeats the bad behavior in the lefthand spot.

Are they on a dimmer switch? If so, are the bulbs dimmable? Dimmers are notoriously finicky with LEDs.

I would suspect the fixture base, ( where you screw in the bulb) is compromised.  Try to just tighten the bulb more.

HoneyDo - Not dimmable switch now. For 7 yrs they were on dimmable switch - first w/ incandescent bulbs, then dimmable LED bulbs. The original flicker/failure involved dimmable switch with dimmable LEDs. We switched out the failing bulb. Problem reappeared. That led us to switching out dimmable switch, replaced w/ normal switch, & replaced dimmable LED w/ non-dimmable LED. (Trying to reduce all variables.) Just now swapped the bulb in failing left pendant w/ bulb in working right pendant. Failing bulb still failing in working right pendant. So coincidence that left pendant wears out bulbs?

RMDman - the failing bulb in lefthand pendant is dark. Just swapped it into the fine righthand pendant. Not dark but on low flicker. We put that failing bulb from lefthand pendant into a standing lamp & get same low flicker. Working bulb from righthand working pendant is working fine in lefthand pendant. We're wondering if there may be a wiring issue that makes the lefthand pendant wear out bulbs faster than the righthand pendant. To experiment, we've put in two brand new identical bulbs in the lefthand and righthand pendants - to see if again we see the left one wears out its bulb faster.

LED bulbs are funny weird.  Sometimes it is a minor electrical problem/bad contact, sometimes a quality control issue with the bulbs and/or driver.  Might be something with that pendant fixture also.
